# (ASM) How to make a positive integer negative?

Tags: assembly, mips

I am doing some online MIPS ASM exercises, however other ASM languages will be similar.

I am having a problem with the following question.
It requires me to perform 13x. This is easy:

```
## Compute 13x

ori $8,$0,1     # $8 = x

sll $9,$8,2     # x*2^2 = 4x
sll $10,$8,3        # x*2^3 = 8x
addu $10,$9,$10     # 4x+8x = 12x
addu $10,$10,$8     # 12x+x = 13x
```

However, it then says to calculate -13x by adding only **one** more instruction.

My idea was to take the two's complement. However, that is 2 instructions:

```
## Calculate -13x with one additional instruction

nor $11,$10,$0      # 
addiu $11,$11,1     # flip bits and +1 to get two's comp?
```

**How can I compute -13x in one additional instruction?**

I suppose this means my original 13x code is not good since it doesn't seem I can do this with only one instruction.

I can think of 'dirty hacks' to do this but I don't think that is what the professor is looking for.

**NOTE: I am only allowed use the following instructions:**

```
add     
sll
addi        
addiu   
addu        
and
andi        
or      
ori
nor
sub
subu
srl
xor
xori
```

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I'm dumb.

I just worked it out. Simply 0 - 13x!?!?!?

```
subu $11,$0,$10 # 0 - 13x = -13x
```